# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: While Sending the POST request from Angular2 Application to Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I'm trying to send the POST request from my Angular2 (`http://localhost:3000`) app to Rails API url (`POST http://localhost:3003/api/users`) with the following code in my angular service.

```
createNewUser(){
//var params = JSON.stringify({ user:{ first_name: 'Nifras', last_name: 'Ismail', email: 'nifrasismail@gmail.com', contact_number: '+94778990300', user_name: 'nifrasismail', password: 'sdkjnfnsdj'}});
var params = JSON.stringify({
  "first_name":"Nifras"
});
var headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

return this.http.post('http://localhost:3003/api/users',params, {headers : headers})
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

While I am sending this request to my api via angular 2 application, I get the following error on browser console.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:3003/api/users. (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

What is the work I need to do to overcome this issue? The same problem arises for GET method too but adding the following header on rails `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` overcome this issue. However, I could not overcome the issue for POST request

```
after_filter :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to overcome this cross-origin issue and whitelist (allow) the clients.

For development *only* purpose you could allow all the requests.

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options, :put, :delete]
  end
end
```

Comment: Ya. It's work. Let me know what should i do on production environment. Thank you for the great hand

Comment: @NifrasIsmail Its up-to you: you can whitelist (allow) only those addresses which _you want to respond_ to *OR* respond to all the origins in production.

Answer (score 1):

You should add these headers to overcome this problem:

```
after_filter :set_access_control_headers

       def set_access_control_headers

             response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'          
             header['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
             headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
             headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
             headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
             headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
       end
```

Add more headers in `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers']` if sends in the request headers.

Add this for response headers,

```
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. While I'm adding the suggested headers by you. I'm getting the same error on browser console.

Comment: As you are not sending response header that's why this problem is still there.. I'd updated my answer check it

Comment: Sorry to ask. I'm new to rails. How do i send this response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' Could you please tell me which file I need to add this.

Comment: You can use another function to response headers

Comment: FYI, I'm using rails 5.0.0.1.

Comment: What about using `before_filter`?

Comment: Host: localhost:3003
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Is this one you asked?

Comment: and use `before_filter`

Comment: The problem is with request headers.. try the updated answer

Comment: It's fails on the other day. I have found the solution from the below answer of @kapilsdv Thank you for your answers and tries. You are the great supporter on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you have added extension CORS and enable it. For reference: 
[Check here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Create a file named as proxy.conf.json at the root of the project
Paste following in the file: { "/api": { "target": “your API URL”, "secure": false } }
Run cmd as:- ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json